# how to set images inside a layout on screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I need to put two images one below the other in the center of the screen. They need to be in the center. the images will keep changing depending on the code so how do i get the images to work on all screens without moving or the size increasing or decreasing?

I tried using grid view but it seems too much code for two images. it works but is there anything more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this type of design i always create a center point on screen,check below code -

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/center_point" />

<View 
    android:id="@+id/center_point"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image2"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_below="@+id/center_point"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

it will surely works.

All the best

Comment: Could you say why you added <View> tag. Wouldn't it work fine without it?

Comment: @apurva how you will do?Give your answer.

Comment: Image after image and set centerhorizontal true for both

Comment: thanks for the answer. the only question i have is if images of every size fit properly

Answer (score 0):

If u have always only 2 images, you can set it in xml file like that:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

First image centers in parent and the second one centers horizontal and also aligns bottom of the screen.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Make a vertical `Linear-layout` that contains both of your `ImageView`s and then set an equal `layout_weight` for both of them. Set the `layout_centerInParent` true for your `Linear_layout`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/lock_layout_keypad"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You can remove `android:layout_weight`.

Answer (score 0):

Here this code may help you.You must create one LinearLayout and set him vertical orientation and layout_gravity = center horizontal.After that create two image views which are automatic position in center of the screen one below other.I hope this will help you.Happy coding :)

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view_two"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view_one"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>
```